# Контроллер (Spring) и мой пример

Tags: java, массивы, spring, java-ee, controller

В туториале делают вот так:

TopicController

```
@RestController
public class TopicController {

    @RequestMapping("/topics")
    public List<Topic> getAllTopics(){
        return Arrays.asList(
                    new Topic("spring", "Spring Framework", "Spring Framework Description"),
                    new Topic("java", "Core Java", "Core Java Description"),
                    new Topic("javascript", "Javascript", "Javascript Description")
        );
    }
}
```

Topic

```
package com.in.controller;

    public class Topic {

        private String id;
        private String name;
        private String description;


        public Topic(){

        }

        public Topic(String id, String name, String description) {

            this.id = id;
            this.name = name;
            this.description = description;
        }

        public String getId() {
            return id;
        }

        public void setId(String id) {
            this.id = id;
        }

        public String getName() {
            return name;
        }

        public void setName(String name) {
            this.name = name;
        }

        public String getDescription() {
            return description;
        }

        public void setDescription(String description) {
            this.description = description;
        }
    }
```

Почему мы делаем вот так через Arrays.asList()?
 Откуда Arrays вообще?
 Чтобы он мог вызвать asList()? 
Где он?))

```
    return Arrays.asList(new Topic("spring", "Spring Framework", "Spring Framework Description"),
                        new Topic("java", "Core Java", "Core Java Description"),
                        new Topic("javascript", "Javascript", "Javascript Description")
```

Как я понял Arrays.asList, мы представляем массив виде списка, но я не вижу в этом примере массив.

Но если удалить Arrays.asList и оставить просто:

```
 @RequestMapping("/topics")
    public List<Topic> getAllTopics(){
        return      new Topic("spring", "Spring Framework", "Spring Framework Description");
                    new Topic("java", "Core Java", "Core Java Description"),
                    new Topic("javascript", "Javascript", "Javascript Description")
        );
```

То компилятор ругается и говорит:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Вы пробовали искать информацию по [`Arrays.asList`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#asList(T...))? Что именно Вам не понятно с этим методом?

Comment: @defaultlocale я указал выше все вопросы

Comment: Ваши вопросы вызывают вопросы :) Вы вроде бы знаете что такое классы и методы и даже свои создаете. В чем сложность именно с этим методом? Вы читали документацию к нему (ссылка в комментарии выше)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

До Java 9 не было возможности создать список сразу со значениями (если не считать сомнительного по многим причинам способа с double brace initialization), поэтому приходилось либо прибегать к громоздкой конструкции

```
List<Topic> topics = new ArrayList<>();
topics.add(new Topic("spring", "Spring Framework", "Spring Framework Description"));
topics.add(new Topic("java", "Core Java", "Core Java Description"));
topics.add(new Topic("javascript", "Javascript", "Javascript Description"));
return topics;
```

Либо использовать не по назначению утилитарный класс [Arrays](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html), предназначенный для операций с массивами:

```
return Arrays.asList(
  new Topic("spring", "Spring Framework", "Spring Framework Description"),
  new Topic("java", "Core Java", "Core Java Description"),
  new Topic("javascript", "Javascript", "Javascript Description")
);
```

Статический метод `asList` принимает [массив аргументов переменной длины](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/language/varargs.html), конструирует из них список и возвращает его. Начиная с Java 9 можно обойтись без этого костыля:

```
return List.of(
  new Topic("spring", "Spring Framework", "Spring Framework Description"),
  new Topic("java", "Core Java", "Core Java Description"),
  new Topic("javascript", "Javascript", "Javascript Description")
);
```